# How does prometheus make sure counter is thread safety?

Tags: java, thread-safety, prometheus

[image]

it seems io.prometheus.client.Gauge is thread safety but io.prometheus.client.Counter is not.

Why counter.get is always 200000 while a != 200000?
[image]

How does prometheus make sure counter is thread safety?

Answer (score 0):

```
static final ThreadLocal<int[]> threadHashCode = new ThreadLocal<int[]>();
```

Prometheus uses ThreadLocal